# opencv 3.1.0 headers not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Following up from this post: [Errors in Upgrading VC++ project from VS 2010 to VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261079/errors-in-upgrading-vc-project-from-vs-2010-to-vs2012)

Now extracted opencv 3.1.0 to C:\ drive. Have a VS 2012 program that cannot find cv.h header file, with 2 identical errors but in different cpp files. This is the error:

`Cannot open include file: 'cv.h'`

Does anyone know where by default I should extract the opencv program to so VS can find it? I know about adding include and lib paths, so I used `C:\opencv\` and that should have worked but it didn't. The docs on the site describe how it's done for VS2010 and I haven't found nay docs that describe how to do it in VS2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you have configured your solution so far. However, this is how I do it:

1. Set OPENCV_DIR environment variable to `D:\libs\x64\opencv_3_1_0\build\x64\vc12` (of course adapt it to your installation)
2. Create property sheet in Property Manager tab (*View/Other windows/Property Manager*)
3. In *C++/General/Additional Include Directories* add `$(OPENCV_DIR)\..\..\include`
4. In *Linker/Additional Library Dependencies* add `$(OPENCV_DIR)\lib`
5. In *Linker/Input* - for debug solution configuration all .lib files from lib directory with "d" before file extension (for example `opencv_world310d.lib`), for release configuration all remaining.

Create separate property sheets for debug/release x86/x64. Now, when creating new solutions, you just add existing property sheets and have OpenCV configured.

Comment: Aha! I forgot to add the letter 'd' for the debug configuration. Thanks!